# Obtener datos de un tag select para trabajar con ellos en JSP

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario de registro en jsp en el cual se asignan dos roles vendedor y administrador. En el registro pongo esos datos en un select pero cuando intento obtenerlos simplemente no se registra. Yo probe mi metodo para registrar y funciona :

```
public boolean registrar(String nombre, String apellido, int edad, String usuario, String contraseña, String rol)
{
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    try{
        String insert = "insert into usuarios (nombre, apellido, edad, usuario, contraseña, rol) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = getConexion().prepareStatement(insert);
        pst.setString(1, nombre);
        pst.setString(2, apellido);
        pst.setInt(3, edad);
        pst.setString(4, usuario);
        pst.setString(5, contraseña);
        pst.setString(6, rol);

        if (pst.executeUpdate() ==1) {
            return true;
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
     System.out.println("ERROR"+e);   
    }finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(getConexion() != null ) getConexion().close();
            if(pst != null ) pst.close();

        }catch(Exception e)
    {
     System.out.println("ERROR"+e);   
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Este vendria siendo el select:

```
<select name="rol">
            <option value="value1"selected>--Selecciona</option> 
            <option value="0" >Vendedor</option>
            <option value="1">Administrador</option>
</select>
```

Pero al intentar hacer el registro simplemente no pasa y no registra cual podria ser el problema?

De esta manera intento hacer el registro:

```
 String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
    String apellido = request.getParameter("apellido");
    int edad = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("edad"));
    String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
    String contraseña = request.getParameter("contraseña");
    String Rol = request.getParameter("rol");



    Consultas co = new Consultas();

    if(co.registrar(nombre, apellido, edad, usuario, contraseña, Rol))
    {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } else
    {
        response.sendRedirect("RegistroUsuario.jsp");
    }
```

Porque no se registra?

Comment: Te ha salido algún tipo de error en el Intento?

Comment: No solamente aparece como falso el statement del if y vuelve al RegistrarUsuario.jsp, no se si es que no esta capturando la informacion de los input.